# DirectShow USB camera LED flash access

Tags: c++, windows, camera, directshow

I'm using C++ and need to access a USB camera's LED flash feature. I'm currently using DirectShow to interface with the camera in other ways (live preview stream, grabbing samples, etc.).

I found the CameraControl_Flash enumeration element on MSDN, but it appears to be implemented only for Windows Embedded CE 6.0 and Windows Mobile:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa925325.aspx

This won't work, as I'm using Windows 7.

Are there any other standard methods within DirectShow or otherwise to interface with LED flash features? Could anyone offer any other advice concerning this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried QueryInterface'ing for the IAMCameraControl interface from the camera filter?  It may be available and it's worth a try!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to get the IAMCameraControl interface. However, I can't pass in the CameraControl_Flash element since it doesn't exist in my version of strmif.h since I'm not working with the mobile SDK. I tried CameraControl_Focus+1 instead since that's the actual value in the mobile SDK, but no go.

Comment: hmm.  Well, if you figure this out, please post about it, it'd be an interesting one...